# How to use NEST V6 and NEST V7 together in .NET?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I would like to use two different elasticsearch (V6 and V7) and to do that I need to use different versions of NEST (V6 and V7).

I found a tutorial that describes the problem and a possible solution: https://www.elastic.co/cn/blog/nest-and-elasticsearch-net-upgrading-your-codebase

However, If I add the https://f.feedz.io/elastic/all/nuget/index.json to my nuget source, I can't find the NEST.v6 package (only NEST 7.4.0).

If that possible, that the NEST.v6 is not available anymore? If so, does anyone face the same issue as me?